# AWS CLI adding inbound rules to a security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli, aws-security-group

I have written an AWS script that scans all security groups that have a specific tag associated with them. It then modifies the ip address of specified inbound rule or adds the new inbound rule if it doesn't exit

You pass 3 parameters to it, tag associated with the security groups = tagkey, inbound rule name = descname, new ip address = ipaddress

My script works, but there are some errors.

My biggest issue right now is with adding a new inbound rule if it it doesn't exist. My script adds the specified inbound rule if it doesn't exist, but when it loops through another existing inbound rule, it tries to add the new inbound rule again -- which it already added. And then get an error saying that the inbound rule (ip address) already exists.

```
tagkey=$1 #tag associated with inbound rules 
descname=$2 #inbound rule description name 
ipaddress=$3 #new ip address for the inbound rule 

echo "this script runs"

#goes through each security group associated with the tag  -- parses/extracts the group-ID of the security group
for sgroup in $(aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region us-east-1 \
        --tag-filters Key=$1,Values= \
        --tags-per-page 100 | awk -F'/' '{print $2}' | tr -d \"\,); do 
    echo "Inbound rules" for $sgroup

    #goesthrough each group-ip, and pulling the inbound ruleID associated with it 
    for inboundrulematch in $(aws ec2 describe-security-group-rules \
    --filter Name="group-id",Values=$sgroup \
    --query "SecurityGroupRules[*].{RuleID:SecurityGroupRuleId}" \
    --output text); do

        #Takes goes through the inbound ruleID and pulls the description associated with it
        for ruleid in "$(aws ec2 describe-security-group-rules \
            --filter Name="security-group-rule-id",Values=$inboundrulematch\
            --query "SecurityGroupRules[*].{Description:Description}" \
             --output text)"; do 
            #saves the description name and the ruleID together  
            together="$inboundrulematch":" $ruleid"
          
        done

        #If the $descname variable input matches values in the $together variable, the aws modify script is triggered
        if [[ $together == *"$2" ]]; then
            echo "//"
            echo $inboundrulematch
            echo $ruleid 
            echo "//" 

            #if the inbound rule already exists, the IP address is modified
            aws ec2 modify-security-group-rules --region us-east-1 \
                --group-id $sgroup \
                --security-group-rules "SecurityGroupRuleId=$inboundrulematch,SecurityGroupRule={Description=$ruleid,CidrIpv4=$3,IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=0,ToPort=65535}"
        else
            #if the inbound rule doesn't exist, one is created
            aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
                --group-id $sgroup \
                --ip-permissions IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=0,ToPort=65535,IpRanges="[{CidrIp=$3, Description=$2}]"

        fi  
    done
done
```

I get the following error when passing parameter for an inbound rule that doesn't exist

[image: ![enter image description here]

The script adds the new inbound rule since it doesn't exist, and then it tries to add the new inbound rule over and over each time it loops over an existing inbound rule.